# How to get OneDrive folder names in Microsoft Graph API response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I fetch files from OneDrive with this request: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='myFile.txt')` which gives me response containing `parentReference`. I use batch get (using `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch`) to resolve folder names from `parentReference#id` but I reach resource limits soon. I found some examples with `$expand`, for instance I tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='myFile.txt')?$expand=children($select=id,name,parentReference)` but it gives me HTTP 400: "Operation not supported".

I don't insist on `$batch` request or `$expand` operator I only need to get search result with folder names.

Answer (score 0):

To get folder names at each level try this -

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/children?$filter=folder ne null&$select=name
```

AFAIK, currently there is no direct way of getting all folder names at root level itself. Being said that, consider filing [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so that it could be considered for future implementation.

Thanks